# Setting Custom HTTP Header for GWT Forms

Tags: gwt, http-headers

How can I set additional HTTP headers while submitting forms with GWT. 
(I am using FormPanel for building the form)

---

**Summary**

**From accepted answer:**

> HTTP headers cannot be set using FormPanel - FormPanel wraps the standard HTML `<form>`, which doesn't allow setting custom headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP headers cannot be set using `FormPanel` - `FormPanel` wraps the standard HTML `<form>`, which doesn't allow setting custom headers.

To set your own headers use a [`RequestBuilder`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html):

```
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(Method.POST, "http://www.my-server.com");
rb.setHeader("X-My-Header", "VALUE");
Request r = rb.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {...});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but users are submitting a file. So, unless there is a way of uploading a file other than using a form, I will have to figure another solution for my problem.

Comment: @Kaan Did you ever figure out another solution?